# Google Shopping PHP API Last Page ProductList

Tags: php, google-shopping-api

I am cycling through the Product List pages, I know each page returns several fields and one of them is `nextPageToken`, the thing is that so far, all pages have this token, I haven't been able to find a way to recognize the last page.
Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last page is simply the page with no `nextPageToken` in the body it returns